# Pass a member function as argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static, maya

I have a Maya plugin and want to get events for timeChanges. However I need to pass a function that I don't want to be static, but this fail at compilation:

```
void MyClass::initializeCallbacks()
{
    MDGMessage::addTimeChangeCallback((MMessage::MTimeFunction) &timeChanged,this);
}

void MyClass::timeChanged(MTime tim, MyClass* clientData)
{
    <Code>
}
```

I then get the following compilation errors:

```
must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address
  ...&timeChanged,this);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      MyClass::
error: cannot cast from type 'void (MyClass::*)(MTime,
      MyClass *)' to pointer type 'MMessage::MTimeFunction' (aka 'void
      (*)(MTime &, void *)')
```

How can I properly pass a pointer of my function ?

Comment: Pass a `void(*)(MTime&, void*)`, as the error message says. That's the address of a `'void(MTime&, void*)` function. It can often be a good idea to read the error message.

Comment: I am struggling on the void(*). My function is declared void, should I change the function declaration or change the way I am passing it ?

Comment: I saw your duplicate proposal, but the article you point to does a static_cast, and I don't want to be static (gives issues in Maya).

Comment: [Required reading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types)

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: @n.m. Que? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7mpClSPyhk

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If the thing wants a helicopter, you need to pass it a helicopter. If you only have a motorcycle, tough luck. You can't use the thing with it. If you need the thing, build a helicopter. Strap a motorcycle to it if you want.

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/53/59/2d/53592d7f13e8c6a9a5dff90b265017db.jpg